# Return the last not null, nan, and non empty value from a python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How can I return the last not null, not empty, and not nan from a list?
if not exists, then return "null" or a customized message!

I have tried these pieces of codes and none of them is bullet proof:

```
import numpy as np

listF=[0.0,np. NaN,2,0,0.0,""]
print([j for j in listF if j][-1])#returns 2 while should retrun 0

listF=[0.0,np. NaN,np. NaN,0,0.0,np. NaN]
print([j for j in listF if j][-1])#returns nan while should return 0


listF=[]
print([j for j in listF if j][-1])#returns Index out of range


listF=[1,np. NaN,np. NaN,0,0.0,np. NaN]
print([j for j in listF if j][-1])#returns nan while should return 0 

listF=[np. NaN,np. NaN,np. NaN]
print([j for j in listF if j][-1])#returns nan while should return "null"
```

Comment: I believe your second example should return `"null"`/`None`, not `0`

Comment: Actually I need it to return 0 and seems it is working as expected

Comment: Then the logic is unclear, why should the first example ignore the 0s, but not the second?

Comment: Yes, u are right, my mistake, sorry

Comment: I see, I updated accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) (or `numpy.isnan`) to check the NA status. Combine it with a generator and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a default value to handle cases without valid value:

```
from math import isnan

def last_valid(lst):
    return next((x for x in reversed(lst) if x and not isnan(x)), None) # or 'null'

last_valid([])
# None

last_valid([0.0,np. NaN,2,0,0.0,""])
# 2

last_valid([1,np. NaN,np. NaN,0,0.0,np. NaN])
# 1

last_valid([0.0,np. NaN,np. NaN,0,0.0,np. NaN])
# None
```

##### accepting `0` as valid:

Given your update of the rule (0 was initially described as non-valid), you can convert to string in the first test to consider `0` valid:

```
from math import isnan
def last_valid(lst):
    return next((x for x in reversed(lst) if str(x) and not isnan(x)), '"null"')

last_valid([]))
# '"null"'

last_valid([0.0,np. NaN,2,0,0.0,""])
# 0.0

last_valid([1,np. NaN,np. NaN,0,0.0,np. NaN])
# 0.0

last_valid([0.0,np. NaN,np. NaN,0,0.0,np. NaN])
# 0.0

last_valid([np. NaN,np. NaN,np. NaN])
# '"null"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

listF=[0.0,np. NaN,2,0,0.0,""]

output = 'empty list'
for tmp in listF[::-1]:
    if not tmp or pd.isna(tmp):
        continue
    else:
        output = tmp
        break
output
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, your solution is also works like a charm, upvoted

Answer (score 0):

This is the oneliner you almost got.
You have to keep in mind that nan is not false when in a bolean expression!
But always returns false if compared to itself :)

```
print([i for i in list if i and not i!=i][-1])
```

Comment: Thanks Indiano, this is throwing me ''type' object is not iterable' for some of the use-cases, possibly cannot handle when the list is empty